# Linksys router cannot change default password

Tags: wireless-router, firmware

My wireless internet suddenly stopped working today. I have Windows 7 and Lindsys WRT54G router. I tried to log into the Linksys setup router page by typing in www.192.168.1.1 into firefox and it prompted me for a username and password as usual. The problem is when i tried to enter my regular username and password it did not work. I finally solved my problem when I came across this post [here](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r21676751-resetting-Admin-password-on-Linksys-WRT54G-router) and the very last post solved my problem.

It suggested I try username: root / password: admin. For some reason the username and password has been changed. When i tried username: root / password: admin , it worked and allowed me to get into the Linksys setup page. The problem is I can't change the username or password anymore. Every time I want to log into my Linksys setup page I have to enter username: root / password: admin. I can't change the "WPA shared key" (password).  For the security settings I selected WPA2Personal + AES.

Also the post said "If the firmware was upgraded to non-linksys firmware - the default will be different" . The problem is I didn't update anything and I'm worried that someone installed a virus or something or somehow changed the firmware on my router. How did I get non-Linksys firmware on my router?

EDIT: I figured out how to change the password when I log into the Lynksys setup page. Administration --> Management --> password. I still don't understand if my router firmware was changed or who changed it or if it happened by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably hit a bug, not a virus or malicious firmware load. Did the web-based admin UI have a Linksys logo on it? And did it look like the UI you remember from previous times you've use it? If so, then it was probably from Linksys. It probably wouldn't be legal for third-party firmware distributions to include Linksys's logo without permissions, and I doubt Linksys would give permission.

If I were you, I would follow Linksys' instructions for fully resetting your router to the factory default settings, then I would follow the instructions for downloading and installing the latest firmware for your particular hardware revision of the WRT54G, then I would set it up from scratch and see if it'll let me change the admin password.

Please note that the wireless network security password (WPA[2] Pre-Shared Key a.k.a. PSK) is not the same thing as the admin password you use to log into the web UI. The wireless PSK is what allows devices to join your network, but the admin password is the one that allows you to change settings on your router.

Comment: Yes the admin UI looked normal. The font of the lettering, size of the prompt box and everything else looked to be legitimate.

Comment: @JessicaM. Well, based on your update, I think the only thing wrong before was you were confusing your wireless password with your admin password. So you kept changing your *wireless* password but wondering why your *admin* password wasn't changing. If I were you, I'd still take a moment to make sure I had the latest Linksys firmware for my hardware revision of the WRT54G.

Comment: Thank you. I've already tried to update the firmware for my router but there doesn't seem to be any updates. I have version V8.00.05 http://support.linksys.com/en-us/support/routers/WRT54G. I forgot to mention that when I finally tried username: root / password: admin,  the first time I got back into the Linksys router setup page all the settings were reset to default.  I think there was an update or something because an hour or two later Windows 7 suggested I restart my computer for an update. Don't know if they're related but I'm guessing so.

Comment: @JessicaM. Windows 7 updates have nothing to do with router firmware updates. If you had to reboot all your Wi-Fi clients just because you updated your router firmware, that would suck! :) I'm guessing you have the v8 hardware revision of your WRT54G. As far as I can tell, it shipped from the factory with firmware v8.00.05 and was never updated. BTW, please forgive me for saying so, but the WRT54G was introduced in late 2002. That technology is over a decade old (even if you bought your particular unit much later). It might be time to upgrade to a modern 802.11ac wireless router.